# How to remove non numeric characters from an column

Tags: python, pandas

I have been using an column where i have to remove non numeric characters from the column , however i have tried but not working in my case.

**Input data**

```
column1

675@12
##256H8\
A--5647R
NaN
222674
98AB 789
```

**Expected Output**

```
column1

67512
2568
5647
NaN
222674
98789
```

**Code i have been using :**

```
df['column1'] = re.sub("[^0-9^.]", "", str(df['column1']))
```

But its not working , Please suggest the possible way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pandas Series's vectorized *counterpart* of the `re.sub` method `.str.replace` to remove `\D` (match non numeric characters):

```
df.column1.str.replace('\D', '')

0     67512
1      2568
2      5647
3       NaN
4    222674
5     98789
Name: column1, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, Sir, its cleaning the rows but it is also removing all the rows where only Numerical values are present.

Comment: What do you mean ? `222674` is pure numeric but still kept ?

Comment: In my case the rows with only numeric characters are been replaced by NaN

Comment: I think those are not numeric characters but numbers. Try convert the entire column to str first: `df.column1.astype(str).str.replace('\D', '')`